# Problems with Refreshing Table with new DB Entries - Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to add new information to a database via a form. Everytime I do that, the table on the same page should update. MY understanding is, as soon as I load the new data, the table should update automatically. But everytime I add an entry I get following error as soon the loop enters the new add object:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
  Unhandled exception in circuit 'uMIFjdavBGnxaU2MoZBcB4KAxLSW9XS1xZpVzCcsEFY'.
  System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key '8' was not present in the dictionary.
     at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
     at ConsentMgmt.Pages.Consent.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder) in C:\Users\Pascal\source\repos\ConsentMgmt\ConsentMgmt\Pages\Consent.razor:line 46
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

My Table:

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Consents)
        {
            @if (!IsVisible(item))
                continue;

            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    @item.PatientID
                </td>

                <td class="text-center">
                    <ConsentCheckbox Name="@item.PatientID" Hidden="@(!isHidden[item.PatientID])" Consent="@item" PatientID="@item.PatientID" />
                </td>
                <td class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center align-middle">
                    <VersionField Hidden="@isHidden[item.PatientID]" Versions="Versions" Consent="@item" />
                </td>
                @foreach (var additionalItem in item.AdditionalConsents)
                {
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <ConsentCheckbox Name="@(additionalItem.Key + item.PatientID)" Hidden="@(!isHidden[item.PatientID])" Consent="@additionalItem.Value" PatientID="@item.PatientID" />
                    </td>
                }
                <td class="text-center">@item.ConsentDate</td>
                <td>
                    <div hidden="@isHidden[item.PatientID]">
                        <button @onclick="() => ChangeHidden(item)">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div hidden="@(!isHidden[item.PatientID])">
                        <button @onclick="() => Save(item)">Accept</button>
                        <button @onclick="() => Cancel(item)">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
                }
            
    </tbody>
```

The method which is called when I submit the form entries:

```
 private void AddNewConsent(ExtendedConsent consent)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AdditionalConsent> additional in consent.AdditionalConsents)
    {
        if (!additional.Value.Consent)
        {
            additional.Value.WithdrawalDate = consent.ConsentDate;
        }
    }
    _data.Save(consent, Name);
    Consents = _data.GetAll(Name);
}
```

**UPDATE - Added Form**
The Form is an own componentent which is added just above the table on the same page.

```
<div class="card" hidden="@Hidden">
    <EditForm Model="ConsentModel" OnValidSubmit="() => ExtendedConsentChanged.InvokeAsync(ConsentModel)">
        <InputText @bind-Value="ConsentModel.PatientID" /><br/>
        <VersionField Hidden="true" Consent="ConsentModel" Versions="Versions"/><br/>
        @if (!(ConsentModel.AdditionalConsents is null))
        {
            @foreach (var additionalItem in ConsentModel.AdditionalConsents)
            {
                <label>@additionalItem.Key</label>
                <ConsentCheckbox Name="@additionalItem.Key" Consent="@additionalItem.Value" />
            }
        }
        <InputDate @bind-Value="ConsentModel.ConsentDate" />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> HiddenChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public ExtendedConsent ConsentModel { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<ExtendedConsent> ExtendedConsentChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string ConsentName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<ConsentVersion> Versions { get; set; }


    private async Task ChangeHidden()
    {
        await HiddenChanged.InvokeAsync(Hidden != Hidden);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see here a form... You can't submit form data in Blazor. No such concept. Could you please provide more context.

Comment: the error points to a line *ConsentMgmt\Pages\Consent.razor:line 46* which line specifically is that?

Comment: This is the _continue;_ If I delete the continue line and the if statement the error occurs at the _{_ from the first foreach loop. And If I log the objects which enter the _Visible_ Method, the new added object exists.